# sql server Insert if not exists and get the inserted id into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server and working on a project to record logs.

The table has a URL column varchar(max) which has repeating value. I created another table which stores only the distinct URLs and the IDs are stored in the main table

Here is my stored procedure to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    logdate DATETIME,
    id CHAR(15),
    value VARCHAR(max)
    )

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[#TestData] FROM ''' + @pfile + ''' WITH (
    firstrow = 2,
    fieldterminator = ''\t'',
    rowterminator = ''\n''
    )'

EXEC (@sql)

create table #testurl(fld varchar(max))

INSERT INTO #testurl(fld) (
        SELECT distinct (
            CASE 
                WHEN (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) > 0)
                    THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5)) - (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5))), ''))
                END
            ) FROM #TestData )

    INSERT INTO url (urlvalue) (
        SELECT tu.fld FROM #testurl tu WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT urlid
            FROM url u
            WHERE u.urlvalue = tu.fld))

    INSERT INTO [Cyberoam].[dbo].[logmst] (
        DATETIME,
        c1c2,
        c3c4,
        c5c6,
        c7,
        c8to12,
        STATUS,
        username,
        usergrp,
        application,
        category,
        categorytype,
        urlid,
        recvbytes,
        sentbytes,
        fw_rule_id,
        srcip,
        dstip,
        contenttype
        )
    SELECT logdate,
        SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%log_id=%', value) + 7), 2),
        SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%log_id=%', value) + 9), 2),
        SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%log_id=%', value) + 11), 2),
        SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%log_id=%', value) + 13), 1),
        SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%log_id=%', value) + 14), 5),
        CASE 
            WHEN (SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8)) - (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8)))) = 'Allow'
                THEN '1'
            WHEN (SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8)) - (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8)))) = 'Deny'
                THEN '0'
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (ISNULL(PATINDEX('%user_name="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%user_name="%', value) + 11),(CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%user_name="%', value) + 11)) - (PATINDEX('%user_name="%', value) + 11))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%user_gp="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%user_gp="%', value) + 9), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%user_gp="%', value) + 9)) - (PATINDEX('%user_gp="%', value) + 9))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%application="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%application="%', value) + 13), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%application="%', value) + 13)) - (PATINDEX('%application="%', value) + 13))), ''))
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%application_name="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%application_name="%', value) + 18), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%application_name="%', value) + 18)) - (PATINDEX('%application_name="%', value) + 18))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%category="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%category="%', value) + 10), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%category="%', value) + 10)) - (PATINDEX('%category="%', value) + 10))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%category_type="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%category_type="%', value) + 15), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%category_type="%', value) + 15)) - (PATINDEX('%category_type="%', value) + 15))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
           (
            SELECT urlid
            FROM url
            WHERE urlvalue = (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%url="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                            THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5)) - (PATINDEX('%url="%', value) + 5))), ''))
                        ELSE NULL
                        END
                    )
            ),
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%recv_bytes=%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%recv_bytes=%', value) + 11), (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%recv_bytes=%', value) + 11), 20), ''))))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%sent_bytes=%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%sent_bytes=%', value) + 11), (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%sent_bytes=%', value) + 11), 20), ''))))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%fw_rule_id=%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%fw_rule_id=%', value) + 11), (CHARINDEX(' ', value, (PATINDEX('%fw_rule_id=%', value) + 11)) - (PATINDEX('%fw_rule_id=%', value) + 11))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%src_ip=%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%src_ip=%', value) + 7), (CHARINDEX(' ', value, (PATINDEX('%src_ip=%', value) + 7)) - (PATINDEX('%src_ip=%', value) + 7))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%dst_ip=%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%dst_ip=%', value) + 7), (CHARINDEX(' ', value, (PATINDEX('%dst_ip=%', value) + 7)) - (PATINDEX('%dst_ip=%', value) + 7))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END,
        CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(PATINDEX('%contenttype="%', value), 0) <> 0)
                THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%contenttype="%', value) + 13), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%contenttype="%', value) + 13)) - (PATINDEX('%contenttype="%', value) + 13))), ''))
            ELSE NULL
            END
    FROM #TestData
```

This code works fine, but the problem is that the time taken to run bulk insert with a file of around 5 k records increases gradually( as the URL table increases reaching 20 mins with ~ 5k records in it ).Many such file will be inserted.

Need your suggestions as how I can improve the performance or if am I doing something wrong

Appreciate your help very much. Thank you!

Note : It take around 4-7 secs if the URL column is in the same table.
will it make any performance difference if its in the same table or separated?

Comment: If you just run the BULK INSERT without the subsequent table build logic, how long does it take?

Comment: it take 4-7 secs if i keep the URL field in the same table but i think it will effect my performance for select statement that's why i separated it.

Comment: What is the % of record that have Value varchchar (max) longer than 7971 characters? what is the average lengh of this field?

Comment: this field includes logs of all the URLs visited. in internet explorer it goes to a max length of ~2080, but i took it max just to be on the safer side.

Comment: Will reducing the size to 2000 make a huge diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution for this.Here is the solution if someone needs it.
The time taken was long because of the URL being varchar(max).
I deleted the clustered PK index.Added a new column for checksum of url and created a clustered index on it.
And changed :

```
SELECT urlid
        FROM url
        WHERE urlvalue = (@value)
```

to :

```
 SELECT urlid
        FROM url
        WHERE checksum_urlvalue = checksum(@value) nad urlvalue = (@value)
```

This reduced the execution time to 7-8 secs.
Thank you all for your responses.
Happy coding :)