# Sql server query with lots of substrings performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have stored procedure in which i perform a bulk insert into a temp table and perform substring on its field to get the different row required for the main table.
The no. of columns for the main table is 66 and the row added after each run of the sp is approx 5500. 
Code for bulk insert part:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TestData] (
    logdate DATETIME,
    id CHAR(15),
    value VARCHAR(max)
    )

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[#TestData] FROM ''' + @pfile + ''' WITH (
    firstrow = 2,
    fieldterminator = ''\t'',
    rowterminator = ''\n''
    )'

EXEC(@sql)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RETURN 1
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Code for substring part :

```
CASE 
        WHEN (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) > 0)
            THEN (nullif(SUBSTRING(value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8), (CHARINDEX('"', value, (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8)) - (PATINDEX('%status="%', value) + 8))), ''))
        ELSE NULL
        END,
```

This substring code is used in insert into and is similar for all the 66 columns.
It takes around 20-25 sec for the sp to execute. I have tried indexing on temp table,droped foreign keys,droped all indexes,droped primary key but still it takes the same time.
So my question is can the performance be improved?

**Edit:** The application for interface is visual foxpro 6.0.
As sql server is slow with string manipulation and doing all the string manipulations on foxpro now. New to foxpro Any suggestions how to send null from foxpro to sqlserver?
Never worked with null in foxpro 6.0.

Comment: What's the problem with NULLs in VFP? It supports NULLs and you can handle them the same way as in T-SQL.

Comment: Edited. Wanted to know if null can be passed to sql server from foxpro

Comment: I'll try to check in over the weekend, but you mention working with VFP6 too.  But your data is in SQL-Server?  Where is it originating from -- a VFP table?  a CSV file?  What...  Also, if you can show a sample of the primary key and some of the 66 columns and sample data and what you are trying to get out of it, there may be a faster way to pre-manipulate the data in VFP for an easier bulk insert into SQL.  Finally, how many records in the table being bulk inserted.

Comment: Data comes from txt files(these are logs generated by 3rd party firewall). Data is to be stored on sql server. PK is identity column as there is no natural PK in table. I had posted the code here but the coulumns are less than what I am trying to insert now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688303/sql-server-insert-if-not-exists-and-get-the-inserted-id-into-another-table

Comment: Currently trying to do the string manipulation in vfp by opening the file with FOPEN(), and reading each line with fgets(). Is storing this substringed values in a table and then converting the table into a csv or txt file for bulk insert a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not really leveraging the features of `PATINDEX()` here you may want to examine the use of [`CHARINDEX()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  instead, which, despite its name, operates on *strings* and not only on characters. `CHARINDEX()` may prove to be faster than `PATINDEX()` since it is a somewhat simpler function.

Indexes won't help you with those string operations because you're not searching for prefixes of strings.

You should definitely look into options to avoid the excessive use of `PATINDEX()` or `CHARINDEX()` inside the statement; there are up to 4(!) invocations thereof in your `CASE` for *each* of your 66 columns in *every* record processed.

For this you may want to split the string operations into multiple statements to pre-compute the values for the start and end index of the substring of interest, like

```
UPDATE temptable
SET value_start_index = CHARINDEX('status="', value) + 8

UPDATE temptable
SET value_end_index = CHARINDEX('"', value, value_start_index)
WHERE value_start_index >= 8

UPDATE temptable
SET value_str = SUBSTRING(value, value_start_index, value_end_index - value_start_index)
WHERE value_end_index IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Used your suggestion and replaced all patindex with charindex. Performance was boosted by a few secs, now it takes ~ 15-20 secs. It seems sql server hates string manipulation :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is rather slow in dealing with strings. For this number of executions it would be best to use SQL CLR user defined function. There is not much more you can do beyond that.